# Как получить минимальное и максимальное значение из объекта где несколько уровней?

Tags: javascript

```js
let obj = {
  list: {
    0: {time: 1619027127267},
    1: {time: 1619027159803},
    2: {time: 1619027172804}
  }
};

console.log( Math.min(...obj.list) );
console.log( Math.max(...obj.list) );
```

Нужно получить минимальное и максимальное значение ключа `time`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
let obj = {
  list: {
    0: {time: 1619027127267},
    1: {time: 1619027159803},
    2: {time: 1619027172804}
  }
};

let min = Infinity,
    max = -Infinity;

for( key in obj.list ){
  min = Math.min( min, obj.list[key].time );
  max = Math.max( max, obj.list[key].time );
}

console.log( 'min:', min );
console.log( 'max:', max );
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает. А какой более производительней будет ваш вариант или мой?

Comment: @Squeli47 кто его знает как там скомпилируется. Мне ваш эстетически больше нравится, хоть и редьюсы не люблю :)

Answer (score 3):

```js
let obj = {
  list: {
    0: {time: 1619027127267},
    1: {time: 1619027159803},
    2: {time: 1619027172804}
  }
};

let min = Object.values(obj.list).reduce((p, c) => (p.time > c.time) ? c : p);
let max = Object.values(obj.list).reduce((p, c) => (p.time < c.time) ? c : p);

console.log( min.time );
console.log( max.time );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const arr = Object.values(obj.list)
arr.sort((a,b) => a.time - b.time)
console.log(arr[0])//min
console.log(arr[arr.length - 1])//max
```